# How to update a query by comparing email and id in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i need to update a query by comparing id and email but if i give id in where condition it is not working.Here is my code.

**index.php**

```
<td style="width:21%;"><a class="button add" href="editsalaries.php?id=<?php echo $row['user_id'];?>">Edit Salary Details</a></td>
```

**editsalaries.php**

```
<form method="post" action="updatesalaries.php" id="myform">
<input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $username; ?>" name='email'> 
<?php  include "editsalary.php";?>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;width:44%;">
<label>Company Name</label>
<input type="text" name="company_name" value="<?php echo $row['company_name'];?>" />
 <label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="user_name" value="<?php echo $row['user_name'];?>" />
<button type="submit"  class = "medium" style="background-color: #2daebf;">Save</button>
```

**updatesalaries.php**

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$email=$_POST['email']; 
$companyname=$_POST['company_name'];
$name=$_POST['user_name'];
$query=mysql_query("UPDATE user_salary_details SET
       company_name='$companyname',user_name='$name'WHERE email='$email' AND user_id='$id'  
");
```

**editsalary.php**

```
$id=$_GET['id']; 
$res = "SELECT *
FROM user_salary_details
WHERE email ='$username'
AND user_id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($res);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: Show us what you tried with the id in the where condition

Comment: if i add user_id in where condition the data is not updating if i remove that id from where condition it is working

Comment: Which where condition "is not working"?

Comment: You are not submitting the ID with the form, also you need to fetch the ID with POST and not GET once you've added the ID to the form

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: @Shadow in updatesalaries it is not working i need to check both conditions there

Comment: while clicking on edit button iam getting that id and comparing that id in editsalry.php and getting the details but while updating iam able to update

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: You're not setting the id in any way, shape or form.

Comment: That's because the ID is not submitted through the form, the edit link contains `?id=` But when you submit a form the form needs to contain the ID in a input field (most likely of the type hidden).

Comment: @Epodax can you please edit the code

Comment: No, I am not gonna write the code for you, this is basic php / html that you need to understand, I strongly suggest you find some tutorials.

Comment: depends on where `$row['user_id']` and `$username` are populated from and possibly others. Check for errors via PHP/MySQL. we also don't know which MySQL API you're using to connect with.

Comment: @Epodax Solved thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

The form in the first code section does not have any control named id, which means that `$_GET['id']` will not be populated in updatesalaries.php. Place the user id into a session variable or into a hidden control.

Comment: Can you please update that one as iam not getting what you are saying

Comment: The form in the editsalaries.php still does not have a control with the name `'id'`. The link whicj code you provided displays the edit form only, the id is not preserved in the subsequent call to the updatesalaries.php.